# maximal spectrum of $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

What are the maximal ideals in $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$? In particular, I'm trying to answer the following question from my commutative algebra class: What is the number of maximal ideals in $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$ with quotient ring of order 8?

So far, the only maximal ideals I have found are $(x,y)$ and $(x+1,y+1)$.Since $\mathbb{F}_2$ is not algebraically closed (as $x^2+x+1$ has no root in $\mathbb{F}_2$) , I don't think Hilbert's Nullstellensatz applies.

For the quotient ring to have order $8$, it must be generated by some elements $1,a,b$ where $a^2,b^2,ab$ are in the maximal ideal $m$, or $1,a,a^2$ where $a^3 \in m$. But I'm not sure how this helps me find $m$.

Comment: Isn't $f(x,y)\mapsto f(x+1,y+1)$ a homomorphism; indeed a self-inverse automorphism of the ring?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I will edit the post to incorporate that information.

Comment: Yes, $(x+1, y+1)$ is a maximal ideal and so are $(x,y+1), (x+1, y)$. These are all the four maximal ideals with quotient $\mathbb{F}_2$. Why did you expect $x^3\in (x+1, y+1)$? This is not true and not necessary. Can you explain? You should have 64 ($=8^2$) maximal ideals with order 8 quotients.

Comment: I'm confused now. On the one hand, it seems that $(x+1,y+1), (x, y+1), (x+1,y)$ should be maximal ideals by ancientmathematician's comment. $(x,y)$ is clearly maximal, and there are automorphisms that interchange these ideals. But if $x^3 \notin (x+1,y+1)$, then why isn't $(x+1,y+1,x^3)$ a proper ideal containing $(x+1,y+1)$? (This would mean that $(x+1,y+1)$ is not maximal.)  Or is it obvious that $(x+1,y+1,x^3)$ is the whole ring?

Comment: Ideal generated by $x^3, x+1$ is already the whole ring.

Comment: Dear @Mohan, I don't think your answer 64 is correct for reasons explained in my answer. You might  already be convinced by calculating the number of maximal ideals with residue field of order 8 in $\mathbb F_2[x]$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg As always, you are right. I was just calculating the $\mathbb{F}_8$ rational points in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_2}^2$, which I should know is not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Warning**
Despite appearances this is a quite subtle and non trivial question!
**Solution**
Clearly to any maximal ideal $\mathfrak m \subset \mathbb F_2[x,y])$ with residue field $\kappa(\mathfrak m)$ of order $8$ we can associate an $\mathbb F_2$-algebra morphism $\mathbb F_2[x,y]\to \mathbb F_8$.
Since there are $64=8^2$ such morphisms (send $x,y$ arbitrarily to $F_8$) the answer to our problem  is  $64$, right?
Wrong! We have to dismiss the points with residue field of order $2$ (corresponding to morphisms $\mathbb F_2[x,y]\to \mathbb F_2$) of which we have $4$.
OK, so the required number is $64-4=60$, right?
Wrong again! The subtle point is that for each $\mathfrak m$ with residue field of order $8$ we have **three** morphisms $\kappa(\mathfrak m)\to \mathbb F_8$ : they are  obtained by composing one of them with the $3$ elements of $\operatorname {Gal} (\mathbb F_8/\mathbb F_2)$.  Dividing by $3$ we obtain the required result:

**There are 20 maximal ideals in $\mathbb F_2[x,y]$ with residue field of order 8.**

Comment: See also this http://urlz.fr/5cd2 : the number of homomorphisms $\mathbb{F}_p[x,y] \to \mathbb{F}_{p^k}$is $\displaystyle\sum_{\mathfrak{p}, \, k | deg(\mathfrak{p})} deg(\mathfrak{p})$

Comment: The reader should note that the only proper subfield of $\mathbb F_8 = \mathbb F_{2^3}$ is $\mathbb F_2$. If the lattice of subfields were more complicated, then there would be a more involved inclusion-exclusion computation to determine the number of quotients with the given residue field.

Comment: Dear @user1952009:  Indeed my answer comes from the theory of  zeta functions but I didn't want to scare away beginners by invoking such sophisticated tools. It is interesting that often  knowing more advanced tools allows one to solve a problem and **then** to think of more  elementary arguments not involving these tools.

Comment: I am interested in learning more of this theory of finite fields. Is there any reference you would recommend to reading about this? For instance I am still wondering why or how did you come up with the idea of the reside field of order 8 and associated the $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra morphism. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @urpi: Have a look at [this document](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9406107) by Schlichenmaier which neatly explains the link between maximal ideals and algebra morphisms, culminating in the *Observation* on page  18.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgesElencwajg!  I will check it out.